# Indy HTTPS download HTTP Error 403 forbidden

Tags: delphi, http, openssl, delphi-xe2, indy

I'm trying to download a file with the idHTTP component but its not working.
I included both OpenSSL DDLs (libeay32 & ssleay32.dll) to my project folder but its not working.

I'm using the idHTTP component with the TidSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL IOHandler and SSL version SSLv3.

With this code I get an EIdHTTPProtocolException with the message "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden".

Why do I get this error and how can I get the download to work?

```
procedure TForm_Main.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  fs: TFileStream;
begin
  inherited;
  fs := TFileStream.Create('E:\abc.html', fmCreate or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    LoadOpenSSLLibrary;
    IdHTTP1.Get('https://www.testcloud.de/index.html', fs);
  finally
    fs.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Set the `IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent` to some browser's user agent and you'll get it to work. The server doesn't like the Indy's default one and rejects its request.

Comment: Did the job, thank you!

Comment: Also, you do not need to call `LoadOpenSSLLibrary()` manually, `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` will do that internally for you.